CSS Automatic Grid Items Height
I have a question regarding the following code and how does it functions:


.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 200px auto;
    border:solid 3px palegreen;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
}


.grid-item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713877561507-881bf3b1c310?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </body>



How does .grid-item know what height to take?
I thought .grid-item just won't take any height since I didn't specify it but now I am confused.

By default the css grid layouts takes the height of the things that are inside it, in your paradigm it contains images so it will take the height of the images.
To be more precise The css rule .grid-item img { height: 100%; } tells the images to take up 100% of the height of their parent grid items, which ensures that the images fill the entire space within each grid item without distortion.
Furthermore answering your second question in the comments on why Original photo has resolution of 6000x4000 pixels while computed size of each .grid-item is 1633.19x1092.75 pixels. If computed size was 1633.19x4000. It depends on how browsers handle images with object-fit: cover;. This property ensures that the image covers the entire container while maintaining its aspect ratio so it has to do some correcting before rendering it to you like that, but, even without the css rule object-fit: cover I am not really sure how each browser reacts to resizing each image dynamically in order to keep the aspect ration, it's out of the scope of my knowledge.
I hope I helped you a little, if you need any more explanation please tell me.

Original photo has resolution of 6000x4000 pixels while computed size of each .grid-item is  1633.19x1092.75 pixels. If computed size was 1633.19x4000, it actually had sense to me.

yes you are right, makes sense because  it depends on how browsers handle images with object-fit: cover;. This property ensures that the image covers the entire container while maintaining its aspect ratio so it has to do some correcting before rendering it to you like that.

I just tried setting every possible object-fit value, but it didn't change anything; but anyway your explanation about automatic aspect ratio change makes sense. Thank you

I see, perhaps it is a default browser behavior but at this point it's out of my scope of knowledge. Don't forget to mark my answer as "answered" using the green question mark  if you feel it helped you. I'd like to help for people with the same question by seeing this post. I will edit the post in order to include the object-fit part.
